# WebGL does not run properly on Firefox 100

Tags: firefox, three.js, 3d, webgl

So recently I've noticed that I'm getting the error

THREE.WebGLRenderer: Error creating WebGL context

while trying to render a 3D model from a .glb file on Firefox 100

I am almost certain that this is not something to do with my own implementation, as browsing sites with similar feature show that all of them are broken too.

For example,

https://skinbaron.de/en/3dviewer

https://3d.cs.money/item/cxih4kC

https://buff.163.com/market/csgo_inspect/3d?assetid=25633198752

These links work on Chrome, at least on my current build 101.0.4951.54.

Does anyone have an idea whats going on?

Comment: Links work on FF 100, Win10.

Comment: My bad I forgot to specify that i'm on Ubuntu 18.04.6. I just checked and all these links are still broken.

Comment: Navigate to `about:debugging` in Firefox and have a look at the “Graphics” section. Most likely, there is an issue with the graphics drivers on your system.